# Why is my while loop getting skipped?

Tags: c++, while-loop

The program skips over my while loops and ends. Super frustrating. I even put the value of AnsCheck to false right before the while loop. No luck. The program does none of what is in the While loop. Here's the relevant code:

```
bool AnsCheck;
AnsCheck = false;
while (AnsCheck = false)
{
    getline(cin, Ans1);
    if (Ans1 != "T" || Ans1 != "F")
    {
        cout << "Please Enter T for true or F for False" << endl;
        cout << "answer not T or not F" << endl; // debugging
    }
    else
    {
        AnsCheck = true;
        cout << "changed bool to true" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: And because this tends to happen sometimes, that people use assignment where they want to use comparison operators, the golden rule is: Constants to the left. Had you written ``while( false = AnsCheck )``  you would have gotten "cannot assign to constant value".

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn you about the assignment being used as a bool. You should probably turn on `-Wall` (or its equivalent in your compiler).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the comparison operator for equality `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`.

```
while (AnsCheck == false) {
    // ...
}
```

Also, as you mentioned in a comment below this answer, the condition in your if statement is never being evaluated as true. To compare strings, you should use `strcmp`, which returns 0 when the contents of both c-strings are equal. See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) for more information.

```
if (strcmp(Ans1, "T") != 0 && strcmp(Ans1, "F") != 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: THANKS. i feel like dolt.

Comment: Is it something similar with the If loop? I'm having the same kind of problem. The If statement is not recognizing a valid input of F or T.

Comment: @RIDDLEisVoltron No that's a little different. Comparing strings requires a slightly different approach. See cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp

Answer (score 0):

> (AnsCheck = false)

---

You need to write this comparison in the other order, so that 
the compiler can generate an error.

```
(false = AnsCheck)
```

It is a difficult transition to learn.  Check your coding standard.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have already stated, using the comparison operator "==" instead of telling the compiler you're assigning by using "=" and you should be fine.

Change this:

```
while (AnsCheck = false)
```

To this:

```
while (AnsCheck == false)
```

Hopefully this helps. Cheers!